# Should I block indexing of my mobile site?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, mobile, noindex

I notice that Yahoo and Bing have started indexing the mobile version of my website, which is located at /mobile from the root. All of the mobile content is just a reduced layout version of the real site.

Is it going to negatively affect my SEO if the crawlers are seeing two locations that essentially have the same content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using a mobile sitemap?

- [Mobile Sitemaps](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?topic=8493)

Here is an article:

- [Help Google index your mobile site](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/11/help-google-index-your-mobile-site.html)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your implementation is quite flawed. You should research best practice methods for serving mobile optimized content (using device detection - not cloaking, canonical link element) etc, rather trying to band-aid your current situation.

Try looking at:

- https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35312
- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/11/running-desktop-and-mobile-versions-of.html
- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/02/making-websites-mobile-friendly.html

Comment: I read those three articles, I am not sure why you think my implementation is so flawed.

Comment: Apologies if I offended - I meant that creating alternative mobile content under a different address (/mobile) is an edge-case approach that I haven't seen before. Given the amount of advice that is readily available in methods of providing mobile content for both consumers *and* search engines, i was surprised by your approach.

Answer (score 2):

It could cause duplicate content issues, particularly with Google. If the content is exactly the same I'd block the mobile content from crawlers.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently earlier this month at SMX Advanced Google officially said(paraphrased by author):

> don’t block Googlebot from your mobile site and smartphone Googlebot from your desktop site.

See under the "Don’t Block Mobile Sites With Robots.txt" heading for that particular bit, though there's a lot of other stuff at that article.

Answer (score 0):

i would consider adding a rel canonical tag to the mobile pages which points back to the main site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Definitely do not block any of Google's crawlers from accessing any version of your site. There are certain edge cases with ad bots and others but in this specific example, you wouldn't want to block.
2. Use an XML sitemap to add an alternate tag linking your mobile pages to your desktop equivalent pages OR add the canonical and alternate tags to the mobile and desktop pages, respectively. This will explicitly tell Google the 1:1 relationship between both versions.
3. Housing your mobile site in a directory like /mobile is, in both Google's and my opinion, the least favorable method. It is still ok, but using m.example.com is better and still the best method is making the entire site at www.example.com responsive.
4. If you still want to stay with /mobile or move to m.example.com, I recommend adding this location to a new profile in GWT so you can track crawl activity and other performance data on its own. Then, you could be able to assess the damage and see if this is an issue.

Answer (score -1):

No problems unless you add rel canonical to point to main website.

Comment: Can you explain why this would be the case?   Do you have personal experience or links to references that you could share?