# Mobile site robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I block indexing of my mobile site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/should-i-block-indexing-of-my-mobile-site)

Should I allow webcrawlers to index the mobile versions of my websites? Is that a good practice from a SEO perspective?

Thanks,

James Ford

Comment: Do they differ from your non-mobile version?

Comment: Not really, they are just simplified versions created with jquery mobile.

Comment: Then I would say there is no reason to index them.  Might actually confuse the crawler in which content it should display in the results.